# Numerically Solving equations with Standard Normal CDF and PDF (Optimization) using R

Tags: r, optimization, numerical-methods, equation-solving

How do we go about numerically solving equations of the sort below using R?

[image]

[image]

Please note, this can be shown to be convex and there is a separate thread on this.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158042/convexity-of-function-of-pdf-and-cdf-of-standard-normal-random-variable

This question has been posted on the Mathematics Forum to get Closed Form or other Theoretical Approaches, but it seems numerically solutions are the way to go?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2689251/solving-equations-with-standard-normal-cdf-and-pdf-optimization

Comment: Have you looked at these packages https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html?

Comment: @RalfStubner ... Thanks for your suggestion. I had never come across these packages before. I briefly looked at it. Any further pointers you have would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the build in `optimize` function to directly optimize the original function:

```
g <- function(x, xi) {
  (xi * x + dnorm(xi * x) / pnorm(xi * x))
}

fun <- function(x, xi, K) {
  K * g(x, xi) + (K - x) * g((K - x), xi)
}

optimize(fun, interval = c(0, 10), xi = 1, K = 1)
#> $minimum
#> [1] 1.173975
#> 
#> $objective
#> [1] 1.273246
```

Your original problem f(x) = g(x) can be formulated as a root finding problem f(x) - g(x) = 0. You can then use the `uniroot` function to solve that. See `?uniroot` for details.

Comment: Wow, three lines :-) Thanks .. I will try it out and be in touch if any further questions. Could you also let me know how to solve such equations as shown above, which arise after taking FOC or derivatives on the original minimization problem.

Comment: @user249613 See expanded answer.

Comment: @Thanks again for your very helpful and extremely easy to follow answers.